# How To Prevent Transition Animation To Run Page Load

Tags: html, css, background, css-transitions

I have this HTML code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/music_index.css">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main_container">
      <div class="main_header">
        <center><input type="search" class="main_page_search"></center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And This CSS :

```css
body {
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  font: 12px/1.4 "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Sans",Garuda,Verdana,Tahoma,sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.main_container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 900px;
}

.main_header {
  height: 400px;
  border-top: 8px gray solid;
  background: url(../img/header_bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 1050px;
}

.main_page_search {
  font-family: "Interstate","Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Sans",Garuda,Verdana,Tahoma,sans-serif;
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 60%;
  color: #666;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: background 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.main_page_search:focus {
  background-color: white;
}
```

My problem is that when I refresh the page the background of the search input becomes white and then come back to gray which means the transition is happening while I'm not clicking on the input how do I prevent that?

Comment: So you want the `.main_page_search` to have a white background only when you click it?

Comment: It's working fine https://jsfiddle.net/9npsvrcb/, are you sure there is a problem?

Comment: My guessing that you add the class with javascript or something so the transition occur. Am I right?

Comment: I'm surprised that's it's working fine on jsfiddle

Comment: And yeah i want to make the transition work only on click not on page load

Comment: Fixed using this solution https://css-tricks.com/transitions-only-after-page-load/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just added a class of "preload" to the body element.

```
<body class="preload">
```

Then ensure no transitions would happen:

```
.preload * {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
}
```

Then removed that class on page load:

**JQuery**

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("body").removeClass("preload");
});
```

[Quick video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMVysPpoEtI) of the issue